Can a Special Counsel be privately liable in tort for false or malicious prosecution if improperly appointed?
Assume an Attorney-General appoints a Special Counsel but they don't do so in a constitutional manner.
If an improperly appointed Special Counsel prosecutes an individual, would they be privately liable in tort for false or malicious prosecution?

Why would the special counsel be sued for an improper action by someone else?

@Jen If a special prosecutor is appointed and does the job they are appointed to without any sort of corruption or false prosecution would they really get sued? There is a big difference between someone else doing something unconstitutional to appoint a special counsel and a special counsel doing a false prosecution. It is very possible for one to be appointed outside of the rules but the investigation and subsequent prosecution follows all of the rules. If you want to suggest that they get sued for a false prosecution you should at least provide a reason to suggest they did it.

@JoeW How does any of this commentary move us toward an answer to the question? The fact that you don't think something should happen doesn't have much bearing on whether that this is legal.

@Jen That is why I asked the question about why a special prosecutor could be sued because I wanted more information about why the op thought they could be sued based on how they are appointed.

@bdb484 I feel that it helps because it can get the op to provide more information on why they think the special prosecutor could or couldn't be sued based on how they are appointed. As it is the question seems to be making a lot of leaps about the conduct of the special prosecutor and how their work happened based on how they got appointed. It is very possible that the special prosecutor can do a fully justified prosecution even if their appointment is questionable.

@JoeW If OP had useful information about what makes it so the special counsel could or could not be sued, I don’t think they would have asked the question. Are there really details OP could provide that would enable you to provide a useful answer? And if so, is there any reason you can’t just answer anyway by saying, “The prosecutor could be sued if X, but not if Y”?

@bdb484 That doesn't change the fact that the information is critical for an answer as it is very possible for a wrongly appointed special counsel to do a fully legal and justified investigation and prosecution. The method of appointment alone doesn't justify suing the special counsel.

@JoeW If you're correct, that's actually a reason why further information is not necessary. A useful answer can just say, e.g., "Special counsel cannot be held liable based on the method of appointment alone, but may be held liable if the plaintiff proves X."

Can we assume in this hypothetical that the prosecutor reasonably believed that they had been properly appointed?

This would be a question of first impression that any answer to would be a speculative opinion in the U.S., so I have voted to close.

canada
There is no nominate tort known as "false prosecution."
There is a tort known as "malicious prosecution" but it is "an intentional tort that requires proof that the defendant’s conduct in setting the criminal process in motion was fuelled by malice" (Miazga v. Kvello Estate, 2009 SCC 51 at para 56).
The circumstance you have described (if translated into roles that would make sense in the Canadian context) would not establish a tort of false prosecution or malicious prosecution.

Maybe I'm reading too much into it, but I understood the question to be assuming a malicious prosection -- i.e., we know that prosecutors are generally immune from liability malicious prosecutions, but does that immunity still hold if they were not properly appointed?

@bdb484 Wouldn't the malice apply to the person who appointed the prosecutor? Or are you supposing that they appointed a particular processor because they expected them to act maliciously?

I was looking for US Federal law. Is this applicable to that?

@WOPR It doesn’t matter what you were looking for in this context.  People are allowed to and encouraged to give answers for other jurisdictions.
